# Is it possible to add more form requirements when asking questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was curious to know if we could possibly add some form check boxes that can possibly ask a question and provide the option of yes or no such as:

Does your question show your work of what you have tried and where you are having issues?
If the user chooses **NO** then possibly display a message of our requirement and to try and adhere to a standard.

A couple of other question ideas:

- Have you searched to see if this has already been asked?
- Is your question descriptive and are all supporting images and resources attached?
- Is your question a software technical issue that cannot not be submitted or would appear as "You have to be there" or "on the computer" to see what is happening?
- Are you asking for a tutorial in your question?

Comment: With this in mind would it also be possible to link people to questions that have similar keywords to those in their question just incase it has already been answered.

Comment: that is already done in the scroll-able text area when you enter your title.

Comment: Oh ok, but do you have to read them? ...I guess people would get annoyed if reading them was a requirement...

Comment: I think something as complex would require too many changes to the system in general (all SE sites use the same), but there have been discussions about a boilerplate message. Just like the suggested similar questions, perhaps it could be triggered by certain words and show a message accordingly. For example, if you type font identification it could suggest you to try the FI sites first, or if you type tutorial it could warn you about our 'no-tut-policies'.

Comment: I could have sworn SE had a situation where it prevented you from asking a question till you reviewed the list.  I may be wrong.